# Create branch from existing branch's history and push to original branch without merge

Tags: git, version-control

I have a branch `dev` which is ahead by 30 commits. I do not yet want to push these commits as they are a part of a feature which is not yet complete.

I now need to make a small, unrelated change to another file in the codebase and push that change to the `dev` branch.

I cannot figure out the correct process flow here.

In my head I imagine the following:

1. Create a branch `dev-feature-1` of the remote `dev` branch (without my 30 commits).
2. Make and commit the change to this `dev-feature-1` branch.
3. Push the `dev-feature-1` branch explicitly to the `dev` branch.

I'm not sure what the commands for the above 3 points would even be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you can push a branch in git using any other name. So, you should push your `dev` branch using the below to save your work.

```
git push origin dev:dev_Cristian
```

This will create a new branch `dev_Cristian` on the origin repo. Alternatively, you could create the new branch locally and start working on it.

Also, it seems to me that you've been working on the `dev` branch, which is common across developers. This is not a recommended practice. Ideally, you should create a new branch using `git branch dev_feature --track origin/dev`, and rebase this branch `dev_feature` continuously against `origin/dev` so as to pull in changes that the other developers have been making.

---

Coming to your original question, you can create a new branch and push it to the origin using:

```
git branch dev-feature-1 --track origin/dev
... # make your changes
git add filenames && git commit -m "msg"
git push origin dev-feature-1
```

Comment: I see that if I had created a new branch for my feature then I wouldn't have this problem in the first place. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think developing a big feature (more than 2 commits) on a shared branch is a good idea. I suggest forking your own local branch for developing, and merge it into your shared branch(`dev` in your case) when it's done.

In your case, I suggest:

```
git co -b 'dev_my_big_feature'
git co dev
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

Work your small patch on `dev`, your big-feature-project on `dev_my_big_feature`, which would be merged into `dev` only when it's ready.